# What's the behavior of the display: block that makes the image adjust in relation to an inline or inline block?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand the behavior that makes the div adjust perfectly to the image.

I recreated an example of the W3Schools: [text](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_css_image_overlay_fade), and in the example, I encountered a behavior that I cannot understand. In the exercise, we create a div to act as an overlay and position it in relation to a container div. The container div gets its height from the picture inside.
But when mapping the overlay to the container/img, the img must have display block or it will have a sleight overflow on the bottom. I read everything I could and can't seem to find the reason why this happens.

Base image:
[base img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwYs.png)

Img with display set to block:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWHcz.png)

Img with display set to inline-block or inline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJld.png)

I thought that the container div was getting its height from the image element inside, and everything seems to make sense except for this behavior.

If someone could make sense of this for me, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

I was expecting the overlay to fit on to the container with the exact measurements of the image.

I tried all types of displays, heights, and widths; when I use an exact pixel measure, it works, but I want to understand why and not just memorize a workaround to a behavior I don't understand.